# Is Doctrine 2 stable enough for use in a production environment?

Tags: doctrine

i wonder if Doctrine 2 is stable enough to use for a production project?

i guess the project will be finished 3 months from now so maybe then Doctrine 2 will be released in a complete version.

i'm wondering if its smarter to use learn and use doctrine 2 right away instead of learning the current version and then convert everything to version 2. cause i've read that the difference is huge between them.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Doctrine 2 in production for a few weeks now. Performance wise, it is much speedier than Doctrine 1. And it's much easier to develop with. I've had a few minor issues with bugs, or unimplemented features, but nothing that I couldn't work around.

Honestly, I don't think learning Doctrine 1 is terribly worth your time. Development for it will stop in 2011. And the two framework are so different, you're going to need to teach yourself twice.

As mentioned elsewhere, there have been some backwards compatibility API changes between the last Alpha release and the upcoming Beta (which is slated for the end of April), but they haven't been huge.

It's very possible by the time you're really picking up speed with a project, it'll be into the Beta phase.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i also think it would be better to use D2 right away since the learning curve is high. the only thing im concerned about is the lack of good documentation/how-tos compared to D1. cause im not the guy who looks into the library classes to figure out how it works. is there good support for D2 somewhere where you can ask people if you encounter a bug or something that you cant work around/understand? a great suppoert is A-O

Comment: I do agree. At this point, the D2 documentation is almost as good as D1's. Although, for community support, I mostly stick to the bug tracker and mailing list. The core team is pretty helpful. But it's not a widely used technology yet, so the community is still young. But to be honest, I didn't think the D1 community is/was much bigger. If support along the lines of other major OSS frameworks is a big concern, I would actually look outside Doctrine all together.

Comment: how do u create models from yaml files, and database from models. cause it seems not to be documented. could u ask these kind of "noob" questions in the mailing lists? seems like the mailing lists are both for 1.2 and 2.0 all mixed together.

Comment: it feels like im gonna save a lot of time to figure out basic stuff like the ones mentioned above. i would be greatful if you could add me on my msn ajsie@gmail.com. that is if u have time to answer some basic questions like what is the equivalent to Doctrine_core::generateModelsFromDb(). cause it says nothing about it in the documentation. thanks

Comment: my msn: ajsie.yu@gmail.com not ajsie@gmail.com=) if u had time that is to say=)

Comment: Rather than work one-on-one with someone, I've started developing a series of tutorials for D2. You can see the first installment here: http://bit.ly/dARIwg

Answer (score 1):

The difference is huge, but one additional concern is API stability. I think they've stated in some blog posts that the API won't be considered final until a beta release (so far everything's been alpha). So, there's a chance you'll still have to refactor some code to fit any API changes they may make before beta.

I doubt they change anything earth-shattering, but not being able to say so definitively means that it's a little disconcerting for production use. My suggestion would be to at least wait until the first beta release, which should mark the API freeze.

Comment: do you know when that would be roughly. are we talking about weeks or months until the beta release? and do you think its better for me to learn doctrine 2 right away instead of learning 1.2 then just use it for some weeks and have to learn a new version all over again?

Comment: Mentioned in my post below, but the first Beta is slated for end of April. It's been pushed back a couple of times, but with past alpha releases, they usually land within 3 weeks or so of their original target.